# Convert from 64bit number to 32bit number

Tags: php, 32bit-64bit

Trying a lot and just failing..

```
$x = 76561198005785475;
```

I want to this number, turn into this:

```
$y = 45519747;
```

That is the 32bit form of it.

---

Trying to explain with more details:

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/converter.php

1) Put the value 76561198005785475 on the "Decimal (input)" field.
2) Press "DEC to BIN" on the "Binary (Base 2)" field.
3) Count 32 starting from the RIGHT and copy it.
4) Paste the 32 chars binary number on "Binary (Base 2)" field.
5) Press "Bin to Dec" button on the "Binary (Base 2)" field.

Ok, now you can see the "45519747" number.

Comment: What you want makes no sense. A 64-bit number placed into a 32-bit integer would be either be negative or would be an overflow ( depending if we are talking about an unsigned or signed integer ). Explain how you get `45519747` from `76561198005785475`

Comment: @Ramhound: perhaps he did mean 45519744, that is what both Kolink and mine answers give?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari - The point of the comment was to point out that a 64-bit integer can only be truncated into a 32-bit number.  Even if he is looking for `45519744` what he wants makes no sense.

Comment: @Ramhound: I know it makes no sense, but if he wants it, why shouldn't we give him the "solution"?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari - We need to stay on topic.  We should figure out what he is trying to do, instead of trying to give him what he asked for, because what he asked for does not make sense.

Comment: @Ramhound We *did* figure out what he is trying to do. See my comment under the answer.

Comment: Ok, i've added some more information. Sorry for the bad initial explanation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
$y = $x & 0xffffffff;
```

This will truncate your 64-bit value to a 32-bit value, but note that there is absolutely no way to get the 64-bit value back, this is a destructive method.

Comment: Just checked binary values of `$x` and `$y`; this seems to indeed be what the OP wants.

Comment: Getting 45519744, not 45519747 haha. Maybe OP means 45519744?

Comment: Curiously enough, when I tried this very code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) it worked like a charm. And yes, the value I got was 45519747.

Comment: Ok, i've added some more information. Sorry for the bad initial explanation.

Comment: Thanks, i dont know why i get this downvotes :( Thanks to all that helps.

Answer (score 5):

I tried many solution. But no one help me. Finally, following script save my life.

```
function intval32bits($value)
{
    $value = ($value & 0xFFFFFFFF);

    if ($value & 0x80000000)
        $value = -((~$value & 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1);

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: This was a handy copy/paste, thank you. I'm not sure the AND is required against ~$value, though, given you masked it at the start already.

Comment: Actually the 2nd AND is required isn't it for the left-most 32 bits, sorry.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

This is too long to write into a comment, so I'll post it here instead.

@Kolink has the right answer; what you want is that operation. However, note that because your `$x` is too big to be stored in an `int` format anyway, it'll be held as a `float` in 32-bit computers, and `float`s suffer from precision loss. My pet theory on why you get 45519744 instead of the right answer is that your 32-bit computer lost the precision on the last digits. To see this in action, try this [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/):

```
$x = 76561198005785475;
echo (int)$x;
```

That site uses a 32-bit server, and it returns 45519744. This demonstrates the precision loss.

On the other hand, if you go [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) and run:

```
$x = 76561198005785475;
$y = $x & 0xffffff;
```

You get the right answer, because that site is 64-bit.

If you want to do the operation on a 32-bit machine (as you evidently do), I suggest you use [gmp_and](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-and.php) from the PHP GMP extension. Unfortunately I couldn't test to see if it works - I'll leave that to you.

Comment: I'm now on a 64bit windows, and the result is 45519744. In this site that you told, the answer is 45519747. This site is on a 32bit OS.

Comment: @Hor Huh. That's... even more curious. Maybe your PHP is 32-bit?... But what about `gmp_and`? Does it work? Also, [this site](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) (making sure we're talking about the same one) cannot be 32-bit - it stores `$x`, which is bigger than the 32-bit highest int, as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. I was want to consider Overflow when converting from Int64 to Int32. this code worked well for me:

```html
function intval32bits($value)
{
    $value = ($value & 0xFFFFFFFF);

    if ($value & 0x80000000)
        $value = -((~$value & 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1);

    return $value;
}
```