# Converting 64 bit integer to 32 bit on a 32 bit PHP installation?

Tags: php, 32bit-64bit

I am making a website which requires use of the [Steam API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API). However I am having problems with converting a 64 bit integer to 32 bit in PHP.

I saw another post, with an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11691810/3189588), that lead me to using this code:

```
$y = 76561197998705985;

$x = $y & 0xffffffff;

echo $x;
```

However, because I am using xampp which only has 32 bit installation, I am getting a result that is incorrect by 1 (38440256 instead of 38440257).

The other post that I linked to above mentions using the PHP GMP extension to convert on a 32 bit installation, but through the official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-and.php), I see no helpful guidance for someone quite new to this sort of thing.

Some clarification/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the example code?

```
$and = gmp_and("0xffffffff", "76561197998705985");
echo gmp_strval($and) . "\n";

#Convert back to int
$asInt = gmp_intval($and);
```

Comment: Call me stupid, but I get this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function gmp_and() in C:\xampp\htdocs\DotaTestPhps\TestArrayLoop.php on line 3` - Have I missed a step somewhere to initiate the `gmp_and` function?

Comment: It's more likely that you don't have gmp enabled in your php.ini: look for `;extension=php_gmp.dll` and make sure that it isn't commented out, restarting your webserver if necessary after enabling it

Comment: @MarkBaker Ah thanks. I uncommented it but forgot to restart the webserver. The code works!

Comment: I would like to ask, how do I then convert the gmp number back to a regular integer?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this being a floating point rounding issue, once a number exceeds `PHP_INT_MAX` it will silently be converted to floating point and therefore lose precision, see this example on 64-bit PHP:

```
php> PHP_INT_MAX
int(9223372036854775807)
php> 9223372036854775807
int(9223372036854775807)
php> 9223372036854775807 + 1
double(9.2233720368548E+18)
```

You will have to store your number as a string to avoid this issue.

Comment: So the only answer to converting between 64 and 32 bit is to store it as a string? How about the method I saw suggested but don't know about, the PHP GMP extension?

Comment: @k4kuz0 GMP uses Strings / Resources internally, the input has to be a string, otherwise you already lost precision.

Comment: I see. Any help on how to do that? So far I know as much as I could have attained from the other post. I don't know how to use GMP and the documentation doesn't appear to be so helpful (to me at least).

Comment: @k4kuz0 Look at the example in the manual page you linked. I suggest fiddling a bit with the functions to get a feel for it.