# PHP: Convert number to 32 bit in a 64 bit machine

Tags: php, binary

I want to convert `-3` to 32 bit, so it should return `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101`. I tried `decbin('-3')` but it is returning 64 bit result like `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101` in my 64 bit machine. How to get 32 bit result ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php#15914

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky thnx man, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691748/convert-from-64bit-number-to-32bit-number#11691810 worked for me