# How can I implement a JS-style bitwise left shift operator in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am trying to currently bitwise shift values in PHP in comparison to how the result would be in JavaScript. I have tried over solutions in stackoverflow and I have not been able to get it work currently how I would like it to. I am currently running PHP 7.1.

For example in a JS environment such as Chrome WebTools Console running this

`var testValue = 94427771;
(testValue << 5)`

Results in: 
`-1273278624`

Whereas in PHP similar produces the following:

`$testValue = 94427771;
$testValue = ($testValue << 5);
echo $testValue;`

The output is: `96694037504`

I've also tried this function which was posted on stackOverflow

`function shift_left_32( $a, $b ) {
    return ( $c = $a << $b ) && $c >= 4294967296 ? $c - 4294967296 : $c;
}`

Where when you run the code `shift_left_32($testValue, 5);` It returns the value: `3021688672`

How could I go about resolving this please. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to restrict the return value of your bitwise shift to a 32bit signed integer then what you can do is modulo the number to max 32bit signed int and then overflow it.

```
function shift_left_32( $a, $b ) {
    return ( $c = $a << $b ) && $c > 0x7FFFFFFF ? ($c % 0x80000000)-0x80000000 : $c;
}
```

or simpler and more correct with bitwise or:

```
function shift_left_32( $a, $b ):int {
    return ( $a << $b ) | -0x80000000;
}
```

For more information you can take a look at this question: [Convert from 64bit number to 32bit number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11691748/1839439)

Comment: thanks for the reply, worked for that specific value however. E.g. if you try running (-1367706280 << 5) in javascript you get the value -816928000 however if you running the call shift_left_32(-1367706280, 5); with that being your updated function you get the value -43766600960

Comment: Could you check my updated answer and tell me if it works?

Comment: Sorry for the stress, with the new function I achieved the value I wanted but now so some other values I wanted don't work for example I want to do the call: (shift_left_32(0, 5)) - 0 + 99 in javascript format [(0 << 5) - 0 + 99;] this would of returned the value 99; now I get the value of -2147483549. If there any way to combine the functionality of the previous function and this new function to get correct values?

Comment: Try with the function from the link: https://3v4l.org/YPHku If it works then let's close as duplicate, so I won't take the credit

Comment: Think that is working, now I think I have an issue with bitwise AND. When I do execute in JS -2833227500 & -2833227500 I get the value 1461739796, but in PHP that same execution gives the value -2833227500. Is this something I can query you for help from here? Thanks so far

Comment: Honestly, I think I have proven myself to be unhelpful here so I will mark it as a duplicate and delete my answer. Purposely overflowing numbers sounds pointless. I do not understand why do you want to do this at all?

Comment: Been more than helpful, it's a hashing algorithm I'm converting from JS to PHP that I need to use. So just need the bitwise operations in php to be on point

Comment: But that's the thing. What is broken is JavaScript not PHP. PHP actually can handle 64bit numbers unlike JS.

Comment: Yeah, done a workaround by wrapping the bitwise operations in that intval32bits function you suggested in that external link thanks again